# Custom glossary style not left aligning

Tags: horizontal-alignment, longtable, glossaries

I have an issue with using `glossaries` for my abbreviations. I have defined my own glossary style, because I wish all acronym descriptions to be written with non-capital first letters in the text, but I wish to capitalize the first letter in the glossary. With this, I get left-alignment issues, see example here:

[image: pdfLaTeX output example]

The output above is generated with this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[nogroupskip, nonumberlist, toc]{glossaries}
\newglossarystyle{myglossary}%
{%
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
        {\begin{longtable}{l lp{\glsdescwidth}}}%
        {\end{longtable}}%

    \renewcommand{\glossaryheader}{%
        \Large \bfseries Term & \Large \bfseries Description \\\endhead}%

    \renewcommand{\glossentry}[2]{%
        \textbf{\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{\glossentryname{##1}}} &
        \Glossentrydesc{##1}\glspostdescription\space ##2\tabularnewline
        }%
}

\setglossarystyle{myglossary}
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\makenoidxglossaries
\newacronym{adc}{ADC}{analog to digital converter}

\begin{document}
This is my acronym: \gls{adc}

\printnoidxglossary[sort = letter, type=\acronymtype, title = {Abbreviations}]%
\end{document}
```

Is there anyone with the slightest idea of what's happening here? I have tried all sorts of things, but I don't seem to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This (i.e. centered) is the default alignment for `longtable`. You can make it left aligned by using the optional argument, i.e. say

```latex
\begin{longtable}[l]{l l p{\glsdescwidth}}
```

instead of

```latex
\begin{longtable}{l l p{\glsdescwidth}}
```

Comment: Wow. I cannot believe the solution was so simple. Thank you very much.